# I'm trying to write a program that asks the user for a string and tests whether it is a keyword.

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
import keyword
keywords = (keyword.kwlist)

user_String = input("enter a string: ")

answer = (user_String == keywords)

print ("it is " + str(answer) + " that the string '" + user_String + "' is a 
keyword.")
```

I'm trying to write a program that asks the user for a string and tests whether it is a keyword. But the trouble I'm having is even if I enter a valid keyword it still prints False

Comment: `user_String in keywords`

Comment: can you elaborate a little bit more on your answer?

Comment: @AngelValenzuela `keywords` is a list, `user_String` is just one element of the list, so `==` always evaluates to `False`. `in` checks instead the membership of the list.

Comment: There is a handy method to check the same: `keyword.iskeyword(your_word)`.

Comment: Thank Mr. Bear, who spotted first the problem.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are comparing a string with a collection (keywords).

Instead, try using something like this:

```
if user_String in keywords:
    print("That is a keyword")
else: 
    print("That is not a keyword")
```

Comment: Python needs proper indentation for blocks, and semicolons are not necessary (they are *allowed*, but you should not ever need to use them unless your doing code golf and squeezing everything into one line).

Comment: @Blckknght thanks for that. I'll stick to languages I fully understand to prevent misleading beginners.

Answer (score 0):

You should use "contains" function instead of checking equality.
Moreover, you have a function called isKeyWord(string) that checks this exact thing.